# Endless animated CSS tilted gradient background

Tags: css, css-animations

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%,#ff2f0f), color-stop(50%,#f42f58));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #ff2f0f 0%,#f42f58 50%);
```

[Exmaple on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RVMvR/) of what we have right now.
We're wondering if it is possible to slowly animate the background to make it more interesting instead of just showing a static gradient. Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: What should be the second _state_ of the animation? I mean, the gradient should animate from what we see in the code to.. what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a rotating gradient background. http://jsfiddle.net/f5v5d/

HTML

```
<div id="bgwrap"><div id="bg"></div></div>
<h3>Fancy Backgrounds For Everyone!</h3>
```

CSS

```
#bgwrap {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index:-1;
}
#bg {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;top:0;width:100%;height:100%;
    padding:0;margin:0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, red, gray, red);
    animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: spin 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
    from { transform: scale3d(2,2,1) rotateZ(0deg);  }
    to { transform: scale3d(2,2,1) rotateZ(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from { -moz-transform: scale3d(2,2,1) rotateZ(0deg); }
    to { -moz-transform: scale3d(2,2,1) rotateZ(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from { -webkit-transform: scale3d(2,2,1) rotateZ(0deg); }
    to { -webkit-transform: scale3d(2,2,1) rotateZ(360deg); }
}
@-ms-keyframes spin {
    from { -ms-transform: scale3d(2,2,1) rotateZ(0deg); }
    to { -ms-transform: scale3d(2,2,1) rotateZ(360deg); }
}
```

Comment: In the fiddle preview, the page background is viewable in portions of the spin :/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use CSS animations, you can't animate gradients themselves - they're images created by the browser, not CSS properties - but you can animate properties that affect them such as `background-size` and `background-position`.

[This post](http://www.impressivewebs.com/animating-css3-gradients/) has more detail, as well as useful [examples](http://www.impressivewebs.com/demo-files/animated-css3-gradient-buttons/).

If you want to use JavaScript, you can, of course, very easily change the gradient's individual properties over time. But that's another question.